# Transit Option not working in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google, transit

I have a requirement to create an application which would show public transport routes between a source and a destination which i acheived it successfully. But i found that the transit routes does not seem to work for most of the cities. It works for only a few places. For Eg: I selected source **Mumbai** and destination as **Bangalore**. I get the result as zero results found but in fact there are trains and buses between the routes. Is there any other alternate API that i can use? Any solution that can tackle this issue..Thanks in advance. Please find the below code i have used.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

#map-container, #side-container, #side-container li {
  float: left;
}

#map-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}

#side-container {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 260px;
}
#side-container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#side-container li input {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  width: 210px;
}
#side-container .dir-label {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 3px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 40px;
}

#dir-container {
  height: 525px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 0;
}
#dir-container table {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="side-container">
  <ul>
    <li class="dir-label">From:</li>
    <li><input id="from-input" type=text value="panvel"/></li>
    <br clear="both"/>
    <li class="dir-label">To:</li>
    <li><input id="to-input" type=text value="thane"/></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <select onchange="Demo.getDirections();" id="travel-mode-input">
      <option value="Train" selected="selected">By train</option>
      <option value="walking">Walking</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="Demo.getDirections();" id="unit-input">
      <option value="imperial">Imperial</option>
      <option value="metric" selected="selected">Metric</option>
    </select>
    <input onclick="Demo.getDirections();" type=button value="Go!"/>
  </div>
  <div id="dir-container"></div>
</div>
<div id="map-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Demo = {
  // HTML Nodes
  mapContainer: document.getElementById('map-container'),
  dirContainer: document.getElementById('dir-container'),
  fromInput: document.getElementById('from-input'),
  toInput: document.getElementById('to-input'),
  travelModeInput: document.getElementById('travel-mode-input'),
  unitInput: document.getElementById('unit-input'),

  // API Objects
  dirService: new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
  dirRenderer: new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
  map: null,

  showDirections: function(dirResult, dirStatus) {
    if (dirStatus != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
    {
      alert('Directions failed: ' + dirStatus);
      return;
    }
    // Show directions
    Demo.dirRenderer.setMap(Demo.map);
    Demo.dirRenderer.setPanel(Demo.dirContainer);
    Demo.dirRenderer.setDirections(dirResult);
  },

  getSelectedTravelMode: function() 
  {
    var value =
        Demo.travelModeInput.options[Demo.travelModeInput.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'Train') {
      value = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT;
    } else if (value == 'bicycling') {
      value = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.BICYCLING;
    } else if (value == 'walking') {
      value = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING;
    } else {
      alert('Unsupported travel mode.');
    }
    return value;
  },

  getSelectedUnitSystem: function() {
    return Demo.unitInput.options[Demo.unitInput.selectedIndex].value == 'metric' ?
        google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.METRIC :
        google.maps.DirectionsUnitSystem.IMPERIAL;
  },

  getDirections: function() {
    var fromStr = Demo.fromInput.value;
    var toStr = Demo.toInput.value;
    var dirRequest = 
    {
      origin: fromStr,
      destination: toStr,
      travelMode: Demo.getSelectedTravelMode(),
      unitSystem: Demo.getSelectedUnitSystem(),
      provideRouteAlternatives: true

    };
    Demo.dirService.route(dirRequest, Demo.showDirections);
  },

  init: function() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.6168, 77.2434);
    Demo.map = new google.maps.Map(Demo.mapContainer, {
      zoom: 13,
      center: latLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Show directions onload
    Demo.getDirections();
  }
};

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Demo.init);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Example code please (jsfiddle is good for debugging)

Comment: @ Mapperz : I have edited my question and added the code which i have used for reference.

Comment: @Mapperz - Do i misunderstand something? I think this about data availability, not a coding/API issue. (If you agree, maybe a rollback to the codeless question...?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is an API issue? I think it is a database/system coverage issue.

According to [news.yahoo.com/google-maps-adds-live-transit-data-selected-cities](http://news.yahoo.com/google-maps-adds-live-transit-data-selected-cities-180457201.html) (2011-06-09)

> Google *plans* to expand its live transit coverage into other metropolitan areas worldwide.

(emphasis mine). There are several cities covered by Google Transit, but i suspect it's going to take even the mighty Google a few more years to conquer the whole world.